# IF-ELSE from MySQL based on single row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I try to get the value 'entryScans' from my SQL-table and send it to $output based on the IF-ELSE case. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

include ('config.php');
$TicketNo=$_POST["TicketNo"];
$hash=$_POST["hash"];

$sql = "SELECT TicketNo,hash,entryScans FROM `Tickets` WHERE `TicketNo` = '$TicketNo' AND `hash` = '$hash'" or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($row['entryScans'] = 0){
$output="ok";
}
else if ($row['entryScans'] > 0) {
 $output="maybe";
else{
 $output="error";
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: A single equal sign is used to assign (`=`), two to compare (`==`).

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` it is removed in PHP7. Look into `mysqli_*` or  `PDO` Likewise you are wide open SQL inject taking user data directly like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not processing your results. You just get the total number of rows in `$row` variable.

You need to process your query result by looping method.

Here is the example

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) 
{
    if($row['entryScans'] = 0)
    {
      $output="ok";
    }
    else if ($row['entryScans'] > 0) 
    {
      $output="maybe";
    }
    else
    {
    $output="error";
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing ...

```
if($row['entryScans'] = 0){
```

Which has 2 problems, `=` is assignement, `==` is testing equal to.  The second part is that your fetching the results in...

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

So `$row` is the number of rows, `$result` is the query results...

So to check the number of rows in the result set

```
if($row == 0){
```

etc.

**Update:**

If you want the value of the column entryScans to be used, then you need to change the call of `mysql_num_rows()` to `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, so

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Then you can leave the rest of the code to use `$row['entryScans']`